keyboard lighting cant get change in ubuntu in msi laptop
I have alpha 15 msi laptop and have RGB gaming lighting on backlit keyboard.
I can change the color of ligthing in windows by pressing [fn+ F8] but i can not change in ubuntu version.
please give me sugestions
